# GUI's with Docker

Tags: docker, ros

Im trying to run a GUI within Docker and trying to following the below link.

```
http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI#The_safer_way
```

Using this link, Im trying to implement the the_safer_way method but get the following error in my MAC.

```
Ps-MacBook-Pro:~ p$ docker run -it \
>     --user=$USER \
>     --env="DISPLAY" \
>     --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
>     --volume="/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
>     --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
>     --volume="/etc/sudoers.d:/etc/sudoers.d:ro" \
>     --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
>     osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-full \
>     rqt
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The path /etc/sudoers.d
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
```

Comment: The instructions you're following assume you're on a Linux host. You're running on MacOS which doesn't have an X11 server running like Linux does. See these instructions for MacOS: https://cntnr.io/running-guis-with-docker-on-mac-os-x-a14df6a76efc

Comment: @MarkBooth because a link only answer is frowned upon and I don't have time to reproduce that procedure here.

Comment: @bmitch : Thanks..Im trying to setup in ubuntu now..

Comment: Check also this: https://github.com/turlucode/ros-docker-gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to read https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces ?

> By default, you can share files in /Users/, /Volumes/, /private/, and
>   /tmp directly. To add or remove directory trees that are exported to
>   Docker, use the File sharing tab in Docker preferences

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, which doesn't normally have an X server, you have to do a little more than on a Linux system, as described by [Using GUI's with Docker](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI#The_safer_way).

The article [Running GUI’s with Docker on Mac OS X](https://cntnr.io/running-guis-with-docker-on-mac-os-x-a14df6a76efc) has brief instructions on how to do this, while [Bring Linux apps to the Mac Desktop with Docker](https://blog.alexellis.io/linux-desktop-on-mac/) has more comprehensive instructions, but to summarise:

- Install `socat` so you can *create a connection between the docker container that runs a graphical application and the X window system on our OS X host operating system* using:

  > ```
  > > brew install socat
  > > socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
  > ```
- Install the [Xquartz](https://www.xquartz.org/), the *X Window System on the OS X operating system* using:

  > ```
  > > brew install xquartz
  > ```
- Log out and then back in again.
- Open Xquartz:

  > ```
  > > open -a Xquartz
  > ```
- On the *X11 Preferences* window, select the *Security* tab and ensure the *allow connections from network clients* is ticked.
- Get the IP adress of the host OS:

  > ```
  > > ifconfig en0
  > en0: 
  > …
  > inet 192.168.0.235 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.199.255
  > …
  > ```
- Finally set the DISPLAY environment variable to this IP address followed by `:0` when running the docker container:

  > ```
  > > docker run -e DISPLAY=192.168.0.235:0 gns3/xeyes
  > ```

<sup>From a comment by [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch)</sup>